# Python smbus read data

Tags: python, smbus

Is it possible to read 3 parameters over Smbus?

First, I say which 8 bit are to read or write:

```
bus.write_byte_data(0x08, 0x4E, 0x30)
```

I write follow command (3 parameters):

```
bus.write_byte_data(0x08, 0x4D, 0x10)
```

but I can only read all 8 bits out:

```
bus.read_byte_data(0x08, 0x4C)
```

This reads all 8 bits, but I need something like:

```
bus.read_byte_data(address, cmd, data)
```

This way it makes it hard to program because I get other numbers back if I write something else and then read it again.

Comment: Can you expand on this a bit more? I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Some code would be good (see: [mcve]).

Comment: i think i got it. i need read_block_data and then i can read out the array but it crashes. How do i define a array in python?

Comment: I got it. To call an array "data" is not a good idea and gave me the error. i changed it to array and now it works. Thanks so much for your post. :)

Comment: Uh you're welcome, even though you solved the entire thing yourself ;p

Comment: @AlexanderCécile Thanks :) Now i got 1 last Problem. This "read_block_data" gives me a decimal number back (51). What i need is an 8bit array (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8). How can i convert this? At best with one Line.

Comment: list((bin(51)[2:].zfill(8))

Comment: edit: list(bin(51)[2:].zfill(8))

Comment: inn = [51]

list(bin(inn[0])[2:].zfill(8))

Comment: Add that code to your post, so that it’s easier for people to find :)